# Secondary xmlns on the child element of my XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xname

I am creating an xml file and trying to append the Namespace to the root Node.

```
    doc = new XDocument(new XElement(XName.Get("urlset",  "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"),
```

However, when I do this it appends an empty namespace on the next node, the child node of the XDocument?

Answer (score 1):

Further `XElements` will have an empty namespace as you haven't specified any namespace for them. This then needs to be inidicated on child elements as it differs from the parent namespace. Unfortunately you need to specify the same namespace for all child documents if you want to "fix" this.

Luckily there's a shorthand code to do this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
```

Then initialize all your elements like so:

```
new XElement(ns + ELEMENT_NAME, ...);
```

e.g.:

```
new XElement(ns + "urlset", ...);
```

instead of `XName.Get`.

Comment: I see, however, I need the consequent child nodes to have no namespace.

Comment: @user3529183 You want them to have no namespace or simply no 'namespace attribute' in output XML? If the former, you need to live with the empty xmlns attributes to indicate that the child element's namespace differs from the parent. If the latter, the solution I've presented does just that (namespace is not repeated if it's the same as parent element).